# Change port server in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I have done a restful web service in eclipse. I have configured a server inside eclipse to test it and it works fine but i want to know if its possible to change the default port . Change the 8080 port to another. is dat possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the server view, select the server and change the properties. You can right-click (windows) to get there.

Each server has its own settings plugin, so you may have to search a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Just double click the server you have added in eclipse, and look for Ports will be available right in that view.